# I have python syntax error in django project

Tags: python, django, django-views

first, i am beginner of django and python
i want to make sign up and login service but i have python syntax error

I use python 3.7.3

```html
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST" :
        if request.POST["password1"] == request.POST["password2"] :
            user = User.objects.create_user{
                username=request.POST["username"], password = request.POST["password"]
                if user is not None:
                    auth.login(request,user)
                    return redirect['home']
                else:
                    return render(request, 'login.html', {'error': 'username or password is incorrect'})
        else:
            return render(request,'login.html')
            }
```

in line 8, (user = User.objects.create_user) i have syntax error
help me!

Comment: what's your error looks like ? please add that to your question

Comment: i solve the problem shafik's answer!

Comment: okay that's good. dont forget to mark the answer as accepted answer if you feel the answer was good enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making mistake here

```
user = User.objects.create_user{
                username=request.POST["username"], password = request.POST["password"]
```

Try this

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST["username"],password = request.POST["password"])
```

Comment: really thanks!!! but i have another problem now..in line 11(return redirect('home')) , i have error that Undefined variable 'redirect'

Comment: Include this top of the file `from django.shortcuts import redirect
`

Answer (score 0):

for the problem **(return redirect('home')) , i have error that Undefined variable 'redirect'** the solution is to **from django.shortcuts import redirect**